# Showing users posts on timeline

Tags: php, html

I am creating a social network and the users can write a status on their profile page in a textarea and when they click post status , the info goes into the database and then the user can see the status on their profile page . Right now when I click the post button , the info goes into the database but it doesn't show on the users timeline . Can someone help me on how to do this ?

profile.php:

```
<form action="poststatus.php" method="post">
<textarea rows="5" cols="40" name="body" id="status">
</textarea>
<button id="bt4" type="submit" name="bts">Post status to timeline</button>
</form>
```

home.php:

```
include("connect.php");
include("auth_login.php");

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$body = ''; 
$body = $_SESSION['body'];

$result = mysqli_query($conn ,"SELECT body FROM posts WHERE body='" . $body . "'");

if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
{
 echo $result;
} else {
    echo "You don't have any posts";
}
```

Comment: What is the body session? Need some more details here

Comment: You cannot echo a mysqli result, you need to fetch it first

Comment: @JasonBassett what do you mean body session ?

Comment: @Qirel how do I do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters, you need to fetch the data. As of right now, you were trying to echo the MySqli result.

You also seem like a learner, so I highly recommend navigating to the [Php.net MySQLi Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) to learn more.

However this down below should get you off to a good start...

This is Object Oriented PHP. You can see [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp) for an example as well.

See example code below:

```
//Create connection
$conn = new MySQLi("localhost", "<username>", "<password>", "<database>");
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
//Write the query
$sql = "SELECT body FROM posts";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<p>".$row['body']."</p>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}

$conn->close();
```

Comment: Everything just says `Body does not exist` . I don't know what to fix because there are no errors showing

Comment: Just that else statement

Comment: What are you storing in the session variable `body`? Seems to me it may be empty.

Comment: nothing . it's just body . Do I have to put something

Comment: Isn't this what i'm storing in the session variable ?  `$body = $_SESSION['body'];`

Comment: Glad to hear, mind upvoting my answer as well? @Dada

Comment: I did . But my rep is to low to change the public view

Comment: I have a small problem . The code shows all the posts in the database . How do I show the users own posts on their timeline ?